# Rails and Select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use Select2 to choose a customer on a ticket.
tickets belong_to customers and customers have_many tickets
tickets have a customer_id and customers have many things, including an address, which is the field I want to search on.

"{:class=>"ticket-customer-select"} is not a symbol nor a string" is the error I am currently seeing, although I feel like that error is not my biggest issue!

Thanks!

--Tim

Here is my form.

new.html.erb

```
        <% @title = "New Ticket" %>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.ticket-customer-select').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap'
          });
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

          <br>
          <br>
          <div class='col-sm-12'>
              <div class="panel panel-default" id="buttons">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                 <% if @ticket.category == 'billing' %>
                   I am fresh out of questions.
                   <br>
                   Please add some details below and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

                   <% elsif @ticket.category == 'internet' and @ticket.severity == 'low' %>
                     Ok. Your internet is working, but is having some other problem.
                     <br>
                     Please add some details below and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

                   <% elsif @ticket.category == 'internet' and @ticket.severity == 'medium'%>
                     Ok. Your internet is down, but your cable is still working.
                     <br>
                     Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

                   <% elsif @ticket.category == 'cable' and @ticket.severity == 'low'%>
                     Ok. Your cable is working, but is having some other problem.
                     <br>
                     Please add some details below and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

                   <% elsif @ticket.category == 'cable' and @ticket.severity == 'medium' %>
                     Ok. Your cable is down, but your internet is still working.
                     <br>
                     Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

                   <% else @ticket.category == 'internet_and_cable' %>
                     Ok. Your cable and internet are both down.'%>
                     <br>
                     Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.'%>

                 <%end%>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <%= render partial: 'new_form' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

_new_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for([:admin, @ticket], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:summary) %>
    <br>


    <%= f.form_group :customer_id do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :customer_id, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :address, class: 'ticket-customer-select' %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.form_group :status do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :status, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.select :status, Ticket.statuses.keys.to_a %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.form_group :severity do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :severity, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.select :severity, Ticket.severities.keys.to_a %>        
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.form_group :detail do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :detail, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.text_area :detail, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <br>


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", admin_tickets_path, class: 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

So my syntax was just a little bit off.
Here is the working line.

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :address, class: 'ticket-customer-select' %>
```